# Aws Elemental Media Live Add chat on live stream

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-media-live

I am live streaming with the help of the AWS elemental media live. now I need to add the chat functionality to  this live streaming. I already have a comment service for the posts. how can I reuse the comment service with this live streaming ?

Answer (score 0):

Implementing live chat requires certain capabilities in the player object/ parent web page to do so.  The MediaLive service is designed to be player-agnostic and presently does not implement any live chat features. There are several live chat service providers that offer integrated chat with a live video element, and MediaLive could provide the video element using the streams you already have working now.

On a related note:  a similar service from AWS known as Interactive Video Service ("IVS") does implement live chat and provides a sample player object for doing so.  You can find more information on IVS here:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/media/building-interactive-live-video-experiences-with-amazon-ivs-and-videoflow/

I hope this helps you with your platform workflow.